# How to detect if an object is within a 'using' scope?

Tags: c#, .net

Please see my example code:

```
var testObject = new SomeClass();
using (testObject)
{
     //At this point how can the testObject implicitly know 
     //if it is placed inside a 'using' scope?

     // In other words, how can testObject know that
     // .SomeAction() is being called from within a 'using' scope?

     testObject.someAction();
}
```

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't.   The **using** statement is syntactic sugar for a try/finally that invokes the Dispose() method manually.  Both are perfectly valid use-cases, so it would be improper for your method to check for the using statement explicitly (even if it could -- which it can't).

Comment: Why should testObject know that it is in a "using scope"? Only the compiler must know to call dispose when leaving the scope.

Comment: The real question here is "Why" Why do you want to know if it's in a using scope? If it's supposed to be in using scope, make a wrapper class around it or something.

Comment: @kirk I know how the using statement wroks  @Tim Because I'd like to construct an object that can only have it's methods called if it is placed within a 'using' scope.

Comment: @Roberto. Do you want to force users of your object always to use `using`?

Comment: @Alexander yes. Also, to the person that voted my question into negative, can you at least explain why you would do that?

Comment: Thanks for your answers everyone.  Again, I only wanted to know if it is possible, I was not really looking for advice where there I should or shouldn't actually do that.

Comment: @Roberto: you should maybe have titled your post "Is it possible to detect if an object is within a 'using' scope?" then :)

Comment: @Groky, Maybe so :-)  But then again my question didn't include anything about where-there it is good practice to do so.  I was thinking along the lines of how can it be done (if it can't then so be it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't.

It could get a stack dump to determine where the calling code is, and analyze the code to try to determine what it does. It could look for the `try...finaly` and `dispose` that the `using` block generates, but it could still not tell if it actually was a `using` block or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It would not make any difference anyway. All you are doing is creating the object, calling some methods, then disposing it. Why should the behaviour of `someAction` change depending on whether or not `Dispose` is called some time in the future?

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to construct an object that
>   can only have it's methods called if
>   it is placed within a 'using' scope.

No, that's not possible.

The only reason why you'd *want* functionality like that is to make a guarantee that an object always get's disposed when it leaves scope, and there are much better ways to enforce this logic.

If you're using VS2010, then you can use FxCop's [Dispose objects before losing scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289%28VS.100%29.aspx) for objects implementing `IDisposable`. In the event you create an object without disposing it, FxCop will fail your build -- and that's about as good of a compiler guarantee as you can get for your requirements.

Comment: Another option is to add a finalizer that throws if the object has not already been disposed. I do this for some objects in debug builds.

Comment: Sorry @Juliet, but you cannot assume that it is the only reason I would want functionality like that.  I only wanted to know if it is possible, wasn't really asking for advice on the 'why' part.